# Не удается обновить npm install

Tags: npm, package.json

```
{
  "name": "cost_price_system",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/coreui-pro": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "antd": "^3.23.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "codemirror": "^5.47.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "i18next": "^19.0.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.21.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "4.3.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-codemirror2": "^6.0.0",
    "react-dates": "^20.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.6",
    "react-i18next": "^9.0.10",
    "react-ladda": "6.0.0",
    "react-quill": "1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-resizable": "^1.10.1",
    "react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^1.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "react-text-mask-hoc": "^0.11.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.2.1",
    "react-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://192.168.1.23:8080/",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coreui/coreui-pro-react-admin-template-starter/issues"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/*index.js",
      "!src/serviceWorker.js",
      "!src/polyfill.js"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.10",
    "npm": ">=6"
  }
}
```

*Что за ошибка, гуглил гуглил ничего не помогло*

**npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.3: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**Кто столкнется с подобной проблемой может поможет**

Сначала прописал команду

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Потом заапдейтил

```
npm update
```

*У меня сработало*